# Salesforce Mobile App - Collecting user input / Close modal on device back button

Tags: navigationmixin.navigate, salesforce-mobile-app, lightning-modal

In the Salesforce Mobile App, we have a custom tab with a Lightning component where the user can trigger various actions, and one of the actions requires additional user input. Therefore, a modal (with inputs) pops up, allowing the user to enter required data and perform an action.

The issue is that the device back button (Android) doesn't close the modal but closes the entire application. This is very inconvenient for the user because they expect the modal to close, not the entire application. Is there a way to somehow prevent this?

For example, standard action on Accounts like "Account -> New" opens a different 'modal' window (apparently integrated into the application), see image below. It would be ideal if it were possible to use a similar modal like the one used for standard actions also from custom components (LWC, Aura...).

**Standard Account Creation (Salesforce App Solution)**

- 'New' Action opens 'application integrated' modal. The modal is also different and more consistent with the mobile application than the standard SLDS modal.

[image: Standard Account New Button which opens integrated modal]

- If device back button is pressed, modal is closed

[image: 'Integrated standard modal']

**SLDS Modal inside LWC component to Collect user input (Custom Solution)**

- The modal opens within the application, and the back button closes the entire application (I don't see support to close the modal only).
- It is not consistent with the application.

[image]

**Alternatives? **

What would be alternatives for collecting user input in a mobile application? I tried opening a new 'Tab' / 'App Page' where the user would fill in fields and somehow return to the previous Tab. However, the issue is that within LWC/Aura, there is no support for navigation.back(), actually there is no support on iOS.